# Compile and run extension for Notepadqq?

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, extension, notepadqq

In our college we use a Windows-based text editor, [TextPad](https://www.textpad.com/), to compile and run Java programs using shortcuts:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to save & compile
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to run the program

At home, instead, I use [Notepadqq](http://notepadqq.altervista.org/wp/) for writing Java programs.

Is there any way to add an extension to Notepadqq to enable a **compile & run** keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Notepadqq is a pretty minimal file editor. Would you consider a more convenient programme, such as [GEdit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) (the default editor in Ubuntu)? With GEDit this sort of things becomes considerably simpler.